# I can't choose the custom taxonomy in my custom post type on Gutenberg

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, block-editor

I'm new here and in Wordpress Development.

I have a custom post type that works with a custom taxonomy. In the classic editor, I can choose the category or add new if I want, but when I'm on Gutenberg the option doesn't show it.

Thanks[image: ![Custom Post Type]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTCSp.png)

[image: Custom Taxonomy]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Gutenberg does nearly everything over REST-API, you will have to update your `register_taxonomy` to be shown in REST, as the default value for `show_in_rest` in `register_taxonomy` is `false`.

So, you update your `$args` array in the `function custom_taxonomy` and add

```
'show_in_rest' => true
```

and you should be fine.

Happy Coding!

Comment: Thanks very much bro!

That's work perfectly.

Happy coding!

Comment: If it worked, please accept the answer by clicking the checkmark ;)

Comment: done! thanks for the comment!